# How to limit API to access just one sharepoint list and block all others

Tags: azure, security, sharepoint

We have created a certificate based Azure API that reads a SharePoint (hosted 365) list though power shell, takes the data create updates dates some settings on the list and sets a column as complete so it know the not to do that row again.  This works, but the problem is it can read and write on all SharePoint collections and list.  I am trying to reduce access.

While researching how to do it, I had to assign SharePoint permissions and the directions said to add `Sites.ReadWrite.All` and this allowed it to work.  If I remove the `ReadWrire.All` the scripts stops working. But after finding it had access to all sites, I found I need Sites.Selected permissions.  After reading about these permissions found I can use these commands in power shell:

```
Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission
Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission
Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission
Revoke-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission
```

But I get Access denied on the `Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission`, but a co-work can run it but it returns nothing just a blank line.  All the other commands need a `permissionID` argument which is found with the Get command.

So this is where we are stuck at.  Any idea on what to due to correct this or how to limit the an API to just once Share Point list?